# what do different characters in tload output mean?

Tags: linux

Does anyone know what the different characters in the tload graph output mean? Mostly there are * but I also = and -.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just the graphical (weird) representation of the *last minute* load average of the system over the time.

The "*"s are just the representation of the level of load average. Understand it as a clasical "area graph".  The "-" sings  just define the unities of load, and the "=" substitute the "-" when the bar passes the line that marks the unit of the graph. You can change the scale  with the "-s flag".

A visual example may be clearer:

```
------------------------------------- load 3

                     *  
                     **
--------------------====------------- load 2
    **             ******   **
   ******         *************
  *********       **************
--=========-------==============----- load 1
*************************************
*************************************
*************************************
************************************* load 0
```

In case don't know how to interpret the load average numbers check this [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29)

Comment: can you elaborate on what unities of load stand for and  how it's associated with load average numbers?